# Installing GNU Radio on ubuntu

Tags: python, gnuradio, cheetah

Im trying to install GNU Radio, I need this to be able to install `gqrx` to use my software defined radio dongle.

I have followed the guide at https://www.jeroennijhof.nl/wiki/index.php/Software-Defined_Radio_on_Ubuntu but the installation aborts because cheetah isn't installed. Python-cheetah is in fact installed in its latest version, running `sudo apt-get install python-cheetah` only states that it is already installed.

Does anyone know why GNU Radio doesn't accept that Cheetah is installed?

Output from installation attempt:

```
-- Python checking for Cheetah >= 2.0.0
-- Python checking for Cheetah >= 2.0.0 - not found
CMake Error at volk/CMakeLists.txt:62 (message):
  Cheetah templates required to build VOLK


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: I wrote a shell script to do an installation of GNU Radio and GQRX. https://github.com/jacobzelek/rtl_sdr_kit

Comment: Are you sure that the cheetah version is 2.0.0 or higher? (it should be, but checking cannot hurt). Did you try to uninstall it via `apt-get` and installing it with [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) instead?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to install from source, I have had good results using following on xubuntu in the past:

```
wget http://www.sbrac.org/files/build-gnuradio && chmod a+x ./build-gnuradio && ./build-gnuradio
```

Reference: http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGRFromSource

Note the dependencies for ubuntu in the script and see how they relate to the installation note you referenced.

They are migrating to a PyBOMBS method but I have not yet tried that yet.  In fact, now I generally use MacPorts's package manager since I have moved to Mac and their gnuradio source packages are very up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. (I'm on CentOS7 though so ymmv)  python-cheetah was on my system and was even being found by pybombs.  Run this with the /pybombs directory and see what it says

```
./pybombs search cheetah
```

It "found" cheetah but still didn't install.  I overcame it with this.

```
python -m pip install cheetah
```

After that i tried to install gnuradio again and it found cheetah correctly but it failed due to not being able to find UHD_LIBRARIES.
I followed the instructions [here](http://code.ettus.com/redmine/ettus/projects/uhd/wiki) and [here](http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html) to install USRP Hardware Driver™ software (UHD™).

I restarted and then did`./pybombs install gnuradio`
This time it worked.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't know that "UHD" was a registered trademark -- is that true?

Comment: That's how they've got it on their website.

Comment: I only knew of the "USRP Hardware Driver™", not of the "UHD™"; but you're right. I never cease to learn, it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on an old openSuse 11.3. Was caused by an old executable /usr/bin/python2.6, which cmake found for some odd reason and used it.

(python 2.7 was compiled and installed manually, and calling python reported Python 2.7.13)

After removing the binary /usr/bin/python2.6 and recreating the build directory it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, if you use conda, just:

```
conda install Cheetah
```